# pandas - replace rows in dataframe with rows of another dataframe by latest matching column entry

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes, `df1`

```
   A  B  C
0  a  1  x
1  b  2  y
2  c  3  z
3  d  4  g
4  e  5  h
```

and `df2`:

```
   0  A   B  C
0  1  a   6  i
1  2  a   7  j
2  3  b   8  k
3  3  d  10  k
```

What I want to do is the following:
Whenever an entry in column `A` of `df1` matches an entry in column `A` of `df2`, replace the matching row in `df1` with parts of the row in `df2`

In my approach, in the below code, I tried to replace the first row
`(a,1,x)` by `(a,6,i)` and consecutively with `(a,7,j)`.
Also all other matching rows should be replaced:
So: `(b,2,y)` with `(b,8,k)` and `(d,4,g)` with `(d,10,k)`

Meaning that every row in `df1` should be replaced by the **latest** match of column `A` in `df2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


columns = ["0","A", "B", "C"]

s1 = pd.Series(['a', 1, 'x'])
s2 = pd.Series(['b', 2, 'y'])
s3 = pd.Series(['c', 3, 'z'])
s4 = pd.Series(['d', 4, 'g'])
s5 = pd.Series(['e', 5, 'h'])
df1 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),list(s3),list(s4),list(s5)],  columns =  columns[1::])

s1 = pd.Series([1, 'a', 6, 'i'])
s2 = pd.Series([2, 'a', 7, 'j'])
s3 = pd.Series([3, 'b', 8, 'k'])
s4 = pd.Series([3, 'd', 10, 'k'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2),list(s3),list(s4)],  columns =  columns)

cols =  ["A", "B", "C"]

print(df1[columns[1::]])
print("---")

print(df2[columns])
print("---")

df1.loc[df1["A"].isin(df2["A"]), columns[1::]] = df2[columns[1::]]
print(df1)
```

The expected result would therefor be:

```
   A   B  C
0  a   7  j
1  b   2  y
2  c   3  z
3  d  10  k
4  e   5  h
```

But the above approach results in:

```
   A   B  C
0  a   6  i
1  a   7  j
2  c   3  z
3  d  10  k
4  e   5  h
```

I know i could do what I want with `iterrows()` but I don't think this is the supposed way of doing this right? (Also I have quite some data to process so I think this would not be the most effective - but please correct me If I'm wrong here, and in this case it would be ok to use it)

Or is there there any other easy approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `merge` then `update`

```py
df1.update(df1[['A']].merge(df2.drop_duplicates('A', keep='last'), on='A', how='left')[['B', 'C']])
```

```
print(df1)

   A     B  C
0  a   7.0  j
1  b   8.0  k
2  c   3.0  z
3  d  10.0  k
4  e   5.0  h
```

Comment: Works like a charm, and does not reorder df, which is exactly what I wanted. thx

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(['A'], keep='last').sort_values('A').drop('0', axis=1)
print (df)
   A   B  C
1  a   7  j
2  b   8  k
2  c   3  z
3  d  10  k
4  e   5  h
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the sideeffect of the sorting. For my usecase it would not be a problem, but I think this needs to be kept in mind...